# Gallio won't execute as test execution has already been done

Tags: c#, code-coverage, sonarqube, gallio

My C# solution contains several projects but the sonar module (runned via jenkins) executes the first project matching the test rule

> sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*Test

and them displays the following message for all test projects:

```
14:57:11.371 INFO  - Gallio won't execute as test execution has already been done.
```

Some threads on SO or others indicates the problem is coming from the pattern but my different tries failed ... Any idea ?
The main problem is why it is executing ONLY the first one ?

Answer (score 1):

Gallio is no more supported in recent versions of the C# plugins. If this is possible for you, I suggest that you move on more recent versions of SonarQube and C# plugins.